# How to manually setup the value of a custom form field type in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I've been messing around with custom form field types in Symfony 4 in order to make a form able to crop a picture (using [cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)) and get some JSON generated by a WYSIWYG (using [Quill.js](https://quilljs.com/)).

I managed to make my custom form field using the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and everything is working correctly when it comes to saving data.

I wanna go further and edit some data previously saved in an entity (named "Article" here), I'm passing my entity as a form option under the "edit" key to manually take care of it in my form class ("BackendNewsAddForm.php").

Unfortunatley the usual `$builder->setData()` function can only set data of pre-builded field types. So I'm looking for a "Best practice" way to get the value I wanna set to the template of the corresponding form field type.

**Solution I though of:**

Since the `$builder->setData()` function can set data of pre-builded fields types inside custom field types, I though of adding an hidden widget to each of my custom field types with the value to set for the edit, and bind that value using javascript inside the template. But it doesn't sound really optimized and it's definitely not the "Best practice" way I'm looking for.

Here is the code I'm working on:

BackendNewsAddForm.php (the form class)

```
class BackendNewsAddForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array("label" => "Titre de l'article"))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array("label" => "Description de l'article pour la page d'accueil"))
            ->add('thumbnail', CroppedPictureInput::class, array("label" => "Miniature de l'article"))
            ->add('content', QuillTextArea::class, array("label" => "Contenu de l'article"));

        if(isset($options['data']['edit'])){

            $article = $options['data']['edit'];

            $builder->add('id', HiddenType::class, array("data" => $article->getId()));

            //I tried the solution I though of here, it looks weird
            $builder->setData(array(
                'title' => $article->getTitle(),
                'description' => $article->getDescription(),
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    'cropped_picture_img' => array(
                        "picture_input" => $article->getThumbnail()
                    ),
                    'cropped_picture' => $article->getThumbnail()
                ),
                'content' => array(
                    'quill_textarea_value' => $article->getContent()
                )
            ));
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

CroppedPictureInput.php (the cropped picture field type)

```
class CroppedPictureInput extends AbstractType
{
    public $test = false;

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'compound' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('cropped_picture_file', FileType::class, array('label' => false, "attr" => array("accept" => "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png")))
            ->add('cropped_picture_img', PictureType::class)
            ->add('cropped_picture', HiddenType::class);

        s('buildForm');
        s($builder->getData());
        die();
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cropped_picture';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cropped_picture';
    }
}
```

PictureType.php (the picture type used in CroppedPictureInput)

```
class PictureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'compound' => true,
            'img_src' => "",
            'img_alt' => ""
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('picture_input', HiddenType::class);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['img_src'] = $options['img_src'];
        $view->vars['img_alt'] = $options['img_alt'];
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'picture_type';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'picture_type';
    }
}
```

QuillTextArea.php (the custom textarea type)

```
class QuillTextArea extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'compound' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('quill_textarea', TextareaType::class, array('label' => false))
                ->add('quill_textarea_value', HiddenType::class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'quill_textarea';
    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'quill_textarea';
    }
}
```

I didn't added the templates of each of those custom fields types for readability purposes but if needed I can provide them.

Thank you for your time :)